# Pass image from one component to another React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I upload image. Then I want to pass it to another component which is in another file. How can I do this? Can you explain with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your code which uploads an image?

I believe you don't need to pass an image to another component if you know the path/name of an image.

If you need to pass, you can use props.

In first Component:

> <`AnotherComponent image={pathAndNameOfImageFile} />`

In AnotherComponent, you can access image as:

> this.props.image

Hope this helps you.